# BDD PageObject steps always null?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, bdd, pageobjects

It's been a very long time I've used Selenium webdriver. I know how I want my project to be structurized, but I'm getting NullPointer Exceptions, "because "driver" is null".

Consider the following code for the STEPS DEFINITION:

```
package Steps;

import PageObjects.ResultsPage;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import PageObjects.SearchPage;

public class StepsSearch {

WebDriver driver;
SearchPage Search = new SearchPage(driver);
ResultsPage Results = new ResultsPage(driver);


@Given("I go to Google.com")
public void iGoToGoogleDotCom() {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
}

@Then("I see that I'm on the search page")
public void iSeeThatIMOnTheSearchPage() throws InterruptedException {
    Search.clickAgreedButton();
    Search.seeLogo();

And some more blabla
}
```

with the PAGEOBJECTS for Search looking like this:

```
package PageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import static Helpers.Constants.setWaitingTime.fast;

public class SearchPage {
public WebDriver driver;

public SearchPage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
}

//Here are some Elements I use to perform actions
By searchfield = By.xpath("//input[@name='q']");
By logo = By.xpath("//img[@class='lnXdpd']");
By searchButtonInAutoFill = By.xpath("(//input[@name='btnK'])[1]");
By searchButtonBig = By.xpath("(//input[@name='btnK'])[2]");
By AgreedButton = By.xpath("(//div[@class='jyfHyd'])[2]");
By cookieStatement = By.id("CXQnmb");
By header = By.id("gb");

//Following are methods, waits, clicks, and all other actions
public void enterSearchQuery(){
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, fast);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(searchfield));
driver.findElement(searchfield).sendKeys("Monkey");
}
And some other stuff }
```

With the HOOKS looking like this:
package Steps;

```
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Hooks {

public WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void browserSetup(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@After
public void tearDown(){
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}


}
```

Now, when I change (in the Stepdefintion)

```
 WebDriver driver;
```

to

```
 Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver;
```

it's working "fine", in that two instances of chromedriver get opened (as one is started in the Hooks). When I keep it like this, I get the above mentioned

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.manage()" 
 because "this.driver" is null
```

I'm not getting it. I think I'm doing something wrong with the Webdriver driver calls, but I've hit dead ends for the last couple of hours. I hope you can help me?

Comment: StepsSearch is creating it's own driver variable, but it's unitialized: public WebDriver driver;  Seems like you'd want to pass in a reference to the one created in "Hooks"... public StepsSearch (WebDriver _driver) {....}

Comment: @pcalkins Ok, I think I understand what you mean, but the solution is unclear... Changing public class StepsSearch {     to     public class StepSearch (Webdriver driver) doesn't seem to be working

Comment: don't change class definition, add a constructor to the class that takes a reference to webdriver as an argument to pass in... (having said that I'm not familiar with your framework so maybe this isn't the correct place to do this?)

Comment: You need to "inject" webdriver object to your step definition. For classic cucumber syntax [here](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer) you can find more details and for lambda syntax you can find details [here](https://www.webelement.click/en/cucumber_java_8_selenium_pageobject_picocontainer_tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Just extend Hooks class to StepsSearch and remove Webdriver declaration in StepsSearch